# implementing retry in while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am trying to implement a retry in the while loop. I want to retry 5 times and if the flag becomes true.

```
bool flag = false;
unsigned int count = 5;
while(!flag && count > 0) {
    DataOperation opt = DataUser::Insert(data_point);
    if(opt == DataOperation::DataEnum) {
        UserPointData exist = DataUser::FindUser(data_point->user_id());
        if(exist) {
           exist->attributeData.put(key, value, len_value, client_id, last_modified_date);
            flag = true;
        }
    } else {
        // insert in data_point
        data_point->attributeData.put(key, value, len_value, client_id, last_modified_date);
        flag = true;
    }
    count--;
}
```

- So if flag becomes true, then I will exit out of the loop
- Second case, if flag is false for 5 times, then I will exit out of the loop as well.

Does this look right what I am doing?

Comment: instead of setting a flag to true, you can just `break;` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @Borgleader pointed out, the `flag` variable is unnecessary. You can stick with a `break` instruction and check after the loop if the count is still bigger than zero. If so, means your task succeeded.

```
unsigned int count = 5;
while(count > 0) {
    DataOperation opt = DataUser::Insert(data_point);
    if(opt == DataOperation::DataEnum) {
        UserPointData exist = DataUser::FindUser(data_point->user_id());
        if(exist) {
           exist->attributeData.put(key, value, len_value, client_id, last_modified_date);
            break; // success.
        }
    } else {
        // insert in data_point
        data_point->attributeData.put(key, value, len_value, client_id, last_modified_date);
        break; // success.
    }
    count--;
}

if (count > 0) { /* succeeded within 5 tries. */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing seems fine but possibly more complicated than it needs to be.

For example you don't need to set a flag to exit you can simply call `break;`.

Here is a pattern I sometimes use that maybe simpler:

```
bool succeed_at_doing_stuff()
{
    std::cout << "trying" << '\n';
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int retries = 3;

    while(retries--) // will exit when retries == 0, retries then becomes -1
    {
        if(succeed_at_doing_stuff())
            break; // no need to set a flag

        // take alternative action
    }

    if(retries < 0) // retries was decremented after last check
    {
        std::cerr << "error: gave up - too many retries" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you will use `count` variable only for that purpose, I suggest you to use a for loop so `count` will not be visible and memory of it will be reclaimed after exiting the scope of the loop. And use `break` statement to immediately exit the loop.

```
for(auto count = 0; count<5; ++count) {
    DataOperation opt = DataUser::Insert(data_point);
    if(opt == DataOperation::DataEnum) {
        UserPointData exist = DataUser::FindUser(data_point->user_id());
        if(exist) {
           exist->attributeData.put(key, value, len_value, client_id, last_modified_date);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        // insert in data_point
        data_point->attributeData.put(key, value, len_value, client_id, last_modified_date);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only change I would make is

```
if(opt == DataOperation::DataEnum) {
    UserPointData exist = DataUser::FindUser(data_point->user_id());
    if(exist) {
       exist->attributeData.put(key, value, len_value, client_id, last_modified_date);
        flag = true;
    } else {
      count--;
    }
```

I am not crazy about you setting count to 5 then counting down, as it is more obvious if you increment until you reach 5, but this will work.

You may want to `break` instead of setting flag, unless you are planning on using flag to differentiate between finding a match or exiting due to the conditional.